# jQuery Waypoints and responsive code not playing nicely

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, jquery-waypoints

I have a responsive site here:
http://www.webershandwickseattle.com/

The site uses jQuery Waypoints ( http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/ ) to stick the navigation menu to the top of the screen when you scroll down.

The problem is that if you make your screen really narrow, and then make it really wide again, the ".stuck" class is applied to the menu, and the menu is on top of the header and things get screwed up.

So somehow I need to get Waypoints to remove the ".stuck" class when you change the width of the screen.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

If you place the code ONLY in the media query portion of the CSS it will work.

Here's an example, when width is smaller than 900px the waypoint will not stick, when larger it does:

```
/* Small */
@media (min-width:100px) and (max-width:900px) {
.stickyright {position:relative; width:300px;}
.stickyright.stuck {position:relative; width:300px;}
}

/* Large */
@media (min-width:901px) {
.stickyright {position:inline; width:320px;}
.stickyright.stuck {position:fixed; width:320px;}
}
```